# How to assign row numer from QStringListModel to int object

Tags: c++, qt

I need to assign number of selected row (in on_listView_clicked) to int variable. I tried int variable1 = index.row(); but It doesn't works. Could someone please help?

```
List_qt::List_qt(QWidget *parent)
        : QMainWindow(parent)
    {
        ui.setupUi(this);

        model = new QStringListModel(this);
        QStringList List;

        List << "Some Item1" << "Some Item2" << "Some Item3";

        model->setStringList(List)
        ui.listView->setModel(model);
    }


    void List_qt::on_listView_clicked(const QModelIndex &index)
    {

       int variable1 = index.row(); // this part of code can be compile but doesn't works after running application

    }
```

Comment: What makes you think that it doesn't work? Does it work without assigning to variable?

Comment: There are no actions (for above example) or application crash after clicking on list (in other code)

Comment: What actions do you expect it to do? I don't see any code for doing actions.

Comment: In other code it was for example: void List_qt::on_listView_clicked(const QModelIndex &index)
{ variable1 =1; for(d = alldevs, i = 0; i < variable1 - 1; d = d->next, i++); .... Could it be "variable1 - 1" problem, and to fix it I just need to replace code to for(d = alldevs, i = 0; i < variable1; d = d->next, i++) ?

Comment: What does `qDebug() << index.row()` give you?

Comment: add code that actually should do something to the question.

Comment: In your 'other code' the problem is most likely in `d = d->next`.

Comment: It seems you did not connect the slot function on_listView_clicked() to ListView's signal clicked(const QModelIndex &): connect(ui.listView, SIGNAL(clicked(const QModelIndex&)), this, SLOT(on_listView_clicked(const QModelIndex&)));

Comment: For above code adding signal-slot definition caused expected actions ( although I observed numeration of rows is started from 0). For my other code I replaced i < variable1 - 1 to i < variable and it also works. Thanks @all for help!